# Regular expression to match simple brackets (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know a regex to detect the following (for C# specifically):

Whether a string ends with a text inside simple brackets. For example:

Some matches:

```
this is a string (dsdfgfg)
this is a (string (123456)
```

Here is some sample code that detect whether the string ends with a simple bracket.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string s = "this is a sentence (367662288)";
    var result = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\)$");
    Console.WriteLine(result); // true
}
```

Some non matches:

```
this is a string (fdf
this is a string (dsdfgfg) temp
this is a string (dsdfgfg))
```

By the way space is allowed after the closing simple bracket but no other character.

Thanks

Comment: You probably mean parentheses - http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/brackets-and-parentheses/. And what regexes have you actually tried to solve this problem?

Comment: `new Regex(@"\)$")`, see also [C# Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet)

Comment: @Wimmel - i think this only checks if the string ends with ). I just wrote code to test it.

Comment: What is the code? Please share. And at least one attempt that could show what you tried.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - added it (Wimmel's appraoch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@"\)$"` only matches strings ending with `)`. You might as well write it as `s.EndsWith(")")` and you would get the same results.

You can use

```
@"\([^()]*\)$"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*%5C)%5Cr%3F%24&i=this%20is%20a%20string%20(dsdfgfg)%0D%0Athis%20is%20a%20(string%20(123456)%0D%0Athis%20is%20a%20(string)%20(FF4455GG)%0D%0A%0D%0Athis%20is%20a%20string%20(fdf%0D%0Athis%20is%20a%20string%20(dsdfgfg)%20temp%0D%0Athis%20is%20a%20string%20(dsdfgfg))&o=m) (ignore the `\r?`, it is only for demo).

The regex matches

- `\(` - an opening round bracket
- `[^()]*` - zero or more characters other than a `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a closing round bracket
- `$` - end of string.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/n6oHju):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
public class Test
{
    private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"\([^()]*\)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strs = new string[] {"this is a string (dsdfgfg)","this is a (string (123456)",
            "this is a (string) (FF4455GG)","this is a string (fdf","this is a string (dsdfgfg) temp",
            "this is a string (dsdfgfg))"};
        foreach (var s in strs) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", s, rx.IsMatch(s).ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
this is a string (dsdfgfg): True
this is a (string (123456): True
this is a (string) (FF4455GG): True
this is a string (fdf: False
this is a string (dsdfgfg) temp: False
this is a string (dsdfgfg)): False
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I understood it as well. Just one more question, what is I want to restrict it to numbers only inside the brackets instead of any characters? I tried this but it ddn't work - @"\([^(0-9)]*\)$.

Comment: You mean you want to only match the strings that have `(` + *digits* + `)` at the end? Use `@"\([0-9]*\)$`. Due to `*` quantifier this will also match `()` at the end of a string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Just tested it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:  ([^()]*)\s*$

The \s* say that the end of the string may have zero or more white space characters after the closing parenthesis.